# Why does adobe air command-line tool adl keep saying "Connection failure:xxx"

Tags: air, adobe

Every time I ran an AIR application, even the simplest "Hello World" sample, with adl, it says:

```
Connection failure: Connection refused
```

I didn't try to establish a connection to any website or server. adl complains all the time and it's annoying. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It might be trying to contact a remote time server. From [this blog post](http://thingsilearn.wordpress.com/2008/03/05/notes-on-creating-your-first-adobe-air-application/):

> By default, when an application is packaged, the ADT process attempts to contact a time server to generate a timestamp. If you use a proxy server to connect to the internet (see my previous rant post), you’ll get a ‘connection refused’ error. Yiou can get around this by adding ‘`-tsa none`’ before the file component of the command like so:
>
> `adt -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore sampleCert.pfx -tsa none HelloWorld.air HelloWorld-app.xml HelloWorld.html AIRAliases.js`

Comment: Note, the OP was asking about ADL not ADT.  However, I hit this problem with ADT's time server yesterday, was stumped.  I happened upon your answer, and found it useful for me, just not the original question - hence the upvote.